# How to change the value of datagidview cell if the cell contains null value in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

If a column contains null dbnull value in sql server database then how can i replace it with "N/A" string when i view the database table in datagridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myDataGridView.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "N/A"
```

Comment: The data adapter always retrieves 1 extra empty row after the last row which has some record....Using this method also shows N/A in that empty row in that column (i have used form7.datagridview1.columns(1).defaultcellstyle.nullvalue = "N/A")....How can i avoid showing N/A in that last empty row

Comment: Why is it returning an empty row?  Maybe try setting DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows to False.

Comment: Done this but still same result....It actually does so because of the database i think...Because in my sql server database every table automatically has one extra empty row at the end....Whether i add new records from my vb.net application still it adds 1 empty row at the end of the table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column is a character type and not numeric, you could always alter the SQL that populates the `SELECT` and use:

`ISNULL(col1,'N/A')`

Another option is to do this:

```
DataSet.BindingSource.DataSource.Columns(<columnName>).DefaultValue = <value>
```

Comment: i've tried 2nd option but it's not working....and my database column is of "Int" type